# laravel (with vue and vuex) overriding sendResetLinkEmail but can't pass the data to the api controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I'm creating forgot password on my web application using laravel (with vue and vuex). I found a good tutorial (https://codebriefly.com/vue-js-reset-password-laravel-api/). I try to apply vuex on this tutorial but it not works.

### **Accrording to the tutorial**

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        email: null,
        has_error: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
        requestResetPassword() {
            this.$http.post("/reset-password", {email: this.email}).then(result => {
                this.response = result.data;
                console.log(result.data);
            }, error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

### **I apply Vuex**

*ForgotPassword.vue*

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["requestResetPassword"]),
    request() {
      this.requestResetPassword({
        email: this.email
      })
        .then(response => {
          toast.fire({
            type: "success",
            title: "Password reset email sent"
          });
          this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          });
        });
    }
```

*Vuex action that i created*

```
 requestResetPassword(data){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            axios.post('/reset-password',{
                email: data.email
            })
            .then(response =>{
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                reject(error)
            })
        })
    }
```

*The Api that handle*

```
public function sendPasswordResetLink(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
    }
```

---

When I input the email address for sending password reset link, the error shows up and  it says:

> message: The given data was invalid.
>
> email :The email field is required.

I test the API using postman and it works
[image]

I check the input field to see if it was empty, but it turns out the input field was not empty[image][image]

Is there a way to apply vuex on this tutorial ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Postman, you are putting the `email` field as a param, not as serialized data in the body.  The vue-resource package's `post` method sets the data passed to it as the body, not as URL parameters.  Either add the email to the request parameters, or in your API, make sure you grabbing data from the request body and not URL parameters.

Comment: Your frontend code looks fine, it depends on how your Laravel server handles the request.  Do you handle it as a `POST` request in your controller?

Comment: it was post sir